# ¿Cómo saber el nombre de las columnas de una tabla en SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Para saber el nombre de las columnas de las tablas uso la siguiente sintaxis:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

A lo que me arroja todos los nombres de las columnas de las tablas de mi base de datos.

Con que función podría saber cuáles son los nombres de las columnas que tiene sólo mi tabla `TAB_1`?

La opción de consultar toda la tabla no me parece atractiva.

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_1
```

Hay alguna función?
**Muchas gracias de antemano**

pst: Recién empiezo en SQL.

Comment: Uso SQL server.

Comment: Ok. Buen dato. Como mencioné recién empiezo en SQL.

Comment: Filtra la consulta por `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME`, sin también podrías hacer: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TAB_1`

Comment: Necesitas aprender a usar el `WHERE`

Comment: Inquietud personal: los que preguntan y sobre todo los que respondemos, no deberíamos usar un poco más el buscador del sitio?, preguntas como estas ya debieran estar respondidas hace rato.

Comment: Lo busqué y todos usaban `SELECT * FROM TAB_1`

Comment: Si, es cierto, hay varias preguntas muy "parecidas", pero no ayudan los títulos y en tu caso sino conocías el uso del `where` es difícil deducir la solución. Mi inquietud no apunta necesariamente a tu pregunta, es más bien algo que vengo notando hace tiempo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La información está en la tabla misma que estás consultando, simplemente debes filtrar las columnas de la tabla que te interesa ver, ya que te interesa únicamente el nombre de las columnas, utiliza esta consulta:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
   and TABLE_NAME = 'Prueba'
 order by ORDINAL_POSITION
```

No olvides incluir en tu filtro el nombre del esquema, ya que puede haber distintas tablas con el mismo nombre en distintos esquemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Para que eventualmente esta pregunta quede como canónica, agregaría la forma de conocer los nombres de columnas en versiones de SQL Server anteriores a la 2005 (?), pero que aún son válidas:

**Mediante la ejecución de `sp_columns`**

```
EXEC sp_columns @table_name='tu_tabla'
```

**Mediante la pseudotabla `syscolumns`**

```
SELECT * 
       FROM syscolumns 
       WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tu_tabla')  
       ORDER BY colorder
```

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente script puede ser de utilidad para obtener el nombre de las columnas y alguna información adicional

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, 
       COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,0) as Longitud, 
       DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'TAB_1' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```